# Saltstack type of data

Tags: salt-stack

Recently I started studying `Salt` and I have been looking over the tutorials they offer.

At the moment I am reading something about Reactor System and came upon this:

```
{% if not data['result'] and data['id'].startswith('ink') %}
minion_remove:
  wheel.key.delete:
    - match: {{ data['id'] }}
```

What I don't understand is the purpose and role of the `data` keyword.What does it actually do and represent?

The reason for asking you this is because I see  it to be called similar to a grain: `salt['grains.get ....](...)`

Is this the case of just a particular case or is this something much more important in the `Salt`world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Salt's reactor is reacting to events (see https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/reactor/index.html). They have a `tag` (a usually hierarchical name), and `data` (known in other systems a payload).

Using the `data` and `tag` keywords you can reference them in your states.